# C++ hiding inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, opaque-pointers

I am trying to hide the inclusion of a third party file in a main class header in a library I wrote, from the executables that link it.  What I mean is:

I have a library that I wrote that defines class A.  Class A inherits from class B (which is defined in a third party library). 
Example:

```
// In A.h
#include “B.h”
class A : public B
{
    A* something(A* val);
}

// In A.cpp
A* A::something(A*val)
{
    // Do something
    return val;
}
```

The header file for class B makes some changes to the environment that are ideal for my library, but are harmful to any executable that links my library.  Someone pointed me to Opaque pointers as a potential solution, though I cannot see how I could use them to hide “B”.

Does anyone know a way to hide the inclusion of B.h?  For solutions, C++11 is OK, but linking to additional dependancies (like boost) is not an option.

Comment: Do you really need A to inherit B?

Comment: @drescherjm Unfortunately yes.

Comment: For inheritance you *must* see the definition of `B`. You can avoid this by insteadd providing cast operators to `B&` and `const B&` in your class `A` and using the Pimpl idiom in your implementation.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky, that won't help - any code that uses `B&` must include `B.h` which causes the problem again.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know, but the inclusion is hidden anyways and the client code does not have to include `B.h`, even though it can. In this manner at least compile-time dependencies are avoided. What would be the point of public inheritance anyways, if the `B` interface was not usable at all?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky, perhaps I misunderstood you. When you suggested cast operators I assumed the returned reference would be used by the client code, which it couldn't do if `B.h` wasn't included.

Comment: @MarkRansom I only deal in pointers when it comes to A (there is never an instance of A that is not a pointer), but there are times (in templates that need to be accessable by the executable) when I access a member of a pointer of A, which seems to be a problem at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One normal way to hide the "implementation" in C++ world is by Pimpl/Handle-body/bridge idiom.

Instead of exposing your class A to user of your API, have a handle class that expose only what you want:

In A.h

```
class AImpl;  // forward declaration

class A {
private:
  AImpl* impl;

public:
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

Then have your actual implementation in another file:

AImpl.h

```
#include <B.h>

class AImpl: public B {
private:
public:
  foo();
  bar();
  somethingThatYouDontWantToExpose();
}
```

Comment: Ok, this can definitely work, and answers the original question, but  looking at my code, after implementing the above suggestion I would have an orphaned typedef that uses something from "B.h" and just declaring the typedef like I would the class AImpl above, without any information, does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

The way to use opaque pointers is to forward declare the classes you need to use so you don't need to `include` their definitions. Since you're not including `B.h` the clients of your library won't be polluted by their definitions.

```
// In A.h
class B;

class A
{
private:
    B* opaque;
};
```

Comment: But I am not declaring B as a member of A. A must inherit from B.  Since B is not a pointer in this instance, how can I hide it with opaque pointers?  It does not seem like a viable solution.  I mentioned it only because it was suggested to me, and I could not see how it would solve my issue.

Comment: @latreides, if you really *must* derive from `B` then you're out of options, you're forced to include `B.h` for its definition. But if you can get away with simply having the same methods, just duplicate each method of `B` in `A` and have it call the opaque pointer for implementation.

Comment: Its a complicated inheritance that is much more than just some members and methods.  To be specific, its what the Boehm Garbage Collector requires you to do so that instances of class A will be garbage collected correctly.